# Did the founding fathers think civil wars would be frequent?

Tags: united-states, founding-fathers

I think I remember learning that one of the founding fathers (Thomas Jefferson maybe?) wrote (in a Federalist Paper maybe?) that there would need to be a civil war about once a generation to sustain liberty in the United States.

Is this correct? If so, could someone point me to the document where this was stated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was (to the best of my knowledge) a comment that Jefferson made to Madison, and I believe he was referring to revolutions, not civil wars.  Jefferson was at the time strongly under the influence of the French Revolution, which he thought was a marvelous thing.  Madison pushed back on Jefferson, and he recanted from the position.  I regret that I can't provide a solid source, but I **believe** I read this anecodote in [Jack Rakove's "Revolutionaries"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005OHVLSE).

It is also possible that you're referring to Jefferson's quote ["God forbid we should ever be 20. years without such a rebellion."](http://wiki.monticello.org/mediawiki/index.php/The_tree_of_liberty...%28Quotation%29), which I think in context is a bit more ambiguous.

I recall no evidence that the other founding fathers shared Jefferson's belief.

Comment: yes, it is the second source that i was recalling. Specifically this sentence: "The tree of liberty must be refreshed from time to time with the blood of patriots and tyrants"